# Still getting error after set newxreg=NULL in R

Tags: r, time-series, predict

I am relatively new to R. I was using `auto.arima` and `predict` to predict a time series data. Here is the code I am using:

```
train.arima=auto.arima(train, seasonal=F, xreg=NULL)
train.pd=predict(train.arima, n.ahead=numahead, newxreg=NULL)
```

I am getting this error message, although I already set the `xreg` and `newxreg` as `NULL`

```
Error in predict.Arima(train.arima, n.ahead = numahead, newxreg = NULL) : 
'xreg' and 'newxreg' have different numbers of columns: 1 != 0
```

Could anyone help please??

Comment: Do you have a small reproducible example? For example, can you paste in the output of `dput(head(train))`, `dput(head(test))`?

Comment: what is `numahead`?  Might be better to use `forecast(train.arima, h = 10)` for 10 (arbitrary) predictions.

Answer (score 6):

Use `forecast` not `predict`. `auto.arima` sometimes selects a drift term which cannot be handled by a simple call to `predict`.

Comment: I would upvote this answer five times if I could. This has been driving me crazy for days.